# How to iterate on subgroups in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table looking like

Customer:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | BANK_ID |
-----------------------------------------
|           1 |             a |       b |
|           2 |            b1 |       c |
|           3 |            b1 |       d |
|           4 |             C |       e |
|           5 |             a |       f |
|           6 |            b1 |       g |
```

I have a query that looks for all customer names that are not unique and group them together. It also assigns a row number to the rows in each group.
The output of this query is:

```
RowNumber|customer_id | customer_name |     
1        |       1    |       a       |             
2        |       5    |        a      |             
1        |       2    |        b1     |              
2        |       3    |       b1      |             
3        |       6    |        b1     |
```

I want to iterate on all the groups. For each group I want to join the members of the group with rows in a different table.Is there any way to operate on each sub group and apply  business logic on the items in each sub group ?

for example: let's assume that for each group I want to leave the first customer if all the customers in this group live in the same place and work at the same place.

I have the following table:

|customer id | address | workplace-name |

|1           | street1 | work1|

|2           | street2 | work1|

|3           | street1 | work2|

|4           | street5 | work7|

|5           | street1 | work1|

|6           | street2 | work1|

You can notice that only the customers in the first group live and work at the same place (customers id: 1,5). If you look at the second group (customers id:2,3,6) - they don't all live and work at the same place. 
The result of this query will be: customer id 5 as it's in the same group with customer id 5 and they both live and work in the same place. But customer 5 is the second in this group.

What's the easiest way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do it in a single query. I've created a cursor that does what I want to do: Iterate on all the rows of one table, apply business logic and insert relevant rows to the output table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH A(Customer_id, Customer_name) 
     AS(SELECT Customer_id, Customer_name
        FROM Customer
        WHERE Customer_name IN 
                    (SELECT Customer_name FROM Customer
                     GROUP BY Customer_name
                     HAVING COUNT(Customer_name) >1)
       )
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Customer_id ASC) AS RowNumber
      , Customer_id, Customer_Name
FROM A
ORDER BY Customer_name, Customer_id;
```

Or you can also use JOIN for that

```
WITH A(Customer_id, Customer_name) 
     AS (SELECT c.Customer_id, c.Customer_name
         FROM Customer c
         JOIN 
             (SELECT Customer_id FROM Customer
              WHERE Customer_name IN ( SELECT Customer_name FROM Customer
                                       GROUP BY Customer_name 
                                       HAVING COUNT(Customer_name) >1)
             ) AS c1
         ON c.Customer_id = C1.customer_id)
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.customer_id ASC) AS RowNumber
      , Customer_id, Customer_Name
FROM A
ORDER BY Customer_name, Customer_id;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa349/38)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but your answer generates the second table. As I've mentioned in my question - I know how to create the second table (with the groups). What I want to do is to iterate on each group and apply business logic on each group separately. For example: leave the first row in each group only if all the customers in this group live in the same city and work at the same place. In order to find this information I need to look at another table. I will update my question.